# Error in solution for a separable differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I "solved" the differential equation $x'=x^2-1$ a couple of months ago, now I checked the solution with wolfram and it seem I was wrong...

According to Wolfram the solution should be $x(t)=\displaystyle\frac{1-e^{2(t+C)}}{1+e^{2(t+C)}}$, but mine is $x(t)=\displaystyle\frac{1+e^{2(t+C)}}{1-e^{2(t+C)}}$.

What I did...

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=x^2-1\\t=\int\frac{1}{x^2-1}dx\\=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{x-1}dx-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{x+1}dx\\=\frac{1}{2}(\log(x-1)-\log(x+1))-C\\=\log\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x+1}}-C\\ \implies \log\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x+1}}=t+C\\ \implies \sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x+1}}=e^{t+C}\\ \implies \frac{x-1}{x+1}=e^{2(t+C)}\\ \implies x-1=xe^{2(t+C)}+e^{2(t+C)}\\ \implies  x(1-e^{2(t+C)})=1+e^{2(t+C)}\\ \implies x=\frac{1+e^{2(t+C)}}{1-e^{2(t+C)}}$$.

I can't spot the error.

Comment: $\int \frac{1}{x-1} dx = log|x-1|+C$. If you assume that $x>1$, you get your solution, but if you assume $x$ is close to $0$, then that integral will be evaluated differently. In fact, you have to treat the three intervals $(-\infty,-1)$, $(-1,1)$ and $(1,\infty)$ differently.

Comment: Both your solution and WA's are wrong. One should start from $$\log\left|\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right|=2t+c.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions $x(t)=\displaystyle\frac{1-e^{2(t+C_1)}}{1+e^{2(t+C_1)}}$ and $x(t)=\displaystyle\frac{1+e^{2(t+C_2)}}{1-e^{2(t+C_2)}}$ are the same in fact, but with different $C$. Note that $C$ can be complex. With this form of writing we have the relationship $C_2=C_1+i\pi$

Another equivalent form is $x(t)=\displaystyle\frac{1-c_1e^{2t}}{1+c_1e^{2t}}=\displaystyle\frac{1+c_2e^{2t}}{1-c_2e^{2t}}$ where $c_2=-c_1$

Comment: No, C cannot be complex. All this is just a sloppy repair for the fact that the differential equation was incorrectly solved from the start.

Comment: @ Did : Bring back $x(t)=\displaystyle\frac{1-e^{2(t+C)}}{1+e^{2(t+C)}}$ with $C$ complex into $x'=x^2-1$ and see if it agrees or not.

Comment: No thanks, I will not do such a thing, for the reason explained in my previous comment. The most useful thing to the OP is to help them solve correctly the differential equation, not to solidify their misconceptions.

Comment: Do you agree or not with $x(t)=\displaystyle\frac{1-ce^{2t}}{1+ce^{2t}}$ is solution of $x'=x^2-1$ ?

Comment: You are becoming tiresome... Yes these are solutions, and one can note that you not-so-subtly replaced $e^{2C}$ (WA's version) or $-e^{2C}$ (the OP's version) by some mysterious $c$. And your next step will probably be to claim that this $c$ can be every real number, thus recovering in extremis the full set of solutions after having lost half of it due to an incorrect integration of the differential equation.

Comment: Better, we close this dialogue of the deaf.

Comment: If you plan to continue to avoid addressing the (very simple) mathematical point I am making, then I will regret this posture but indeed the exchange becomes pointless. (Nevertheless, I must mention my puzzlement at the attitude.)